# How yield in for-comprehension works in Scala?

Tags: scala, yield, for-comprehension

Reading this [article](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) and realized that roughly all the functions after `yield` keyword is a `map` function. While all the statements within the `for` are `flatMap` functions. Why is that so? Why can the function after the `yield` be a `flatMap` function and also the functions within `for` are `map` functions?

Comment: For comprehension is just syntactic sugar.  It desugars to flatmap, map and filter according to rules.  Answer to your "why"  is "because rules say so".

Comment: I suggest to first read https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. The final generator, `<-`, inside the `for` (before the `yield`) is translated into a `map()` call. Generators before (above) the final generator are translated into `flatMap()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your first point is roughly correct. The statement

```
for (x <- list) yield f(x)
```

Is equivalent to

```
list.map(x => f(x))
```

But you are not quite right about how `flatMap` is used when there is more than one list.

The `flatMap` call is used if you want to iterate over another list at the same time:

```
for (
  x <- list1
  y <- list2
) yield f(x, y)
```

This is equivalent to

```
list1.flatMap(x => list2.map(y => f(x, y)))
```

The `map` call is wrapped in a `flatMap` call so that the result is a simple list. If the outer call was `map` then the result would be a nested list.

The inner call is always a `map` call, all the outer calls are `flatMap`. So

```
for (
  x <- list1
  y <- list2
  z <- list3
) yield f(x, y, z)
```

Is

```
list1.flatMap(x => list2.flatMap(y => list3.map(z => f(x, y, z))))
```

In the end the best thing to do with `for` is to experiment with it until it does what you want, and after a while it will become intuitive.